# Answering own questions (as a way to share code-snippets)

Tags: discussion

Recently I was asked about a script I wrote for a project (just a small utility, nothing worth releasing as an addon).

And I figured others may find it useful, so I posted it as a Q&A (here - [Render Videos From Marker Ranges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15372)).

Small snippets like this don't really have a good place to go at the moment,

There was a **Blending into Python** cookbook, so perhaps that can be updated and better maintained.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Blending_Into_Python/Cookbook

So my question is:

If we have useful code-snippets we think others would find useful, either as examples or in their own right. Is it reasonable to post them as Questions, then answer our own questions and include the script?

*Again, this is only for small scripts - entire addons better be in version control and linked to.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question and answer are both valid and useful so I see no problem with this now or in the future. One purpose of this site is to create an archive of useful answers and self contained resources to common problems. As long as it is in our scope it should be fine to post these.

Comment: Obscure or irrelevant scripts wont get voted up... so, as long as theres not 100's of zero voted scripts clogging up SE (which seems unlikely), its fine I suppose.

Comment: IIRC, the system automatically deletes questions with no votes and low views after a while.